# How do I move text to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate www.google.com, and if you see on the top there is 'About' and 'Store' on the left and 'Images' and 'Gmail' on the right. How exactly can I get the Images and Gmail to the right side, while preserving space between the words?

I tried padding, but that messed up the format, and float: right; pushed what I wanted to the right, but put 0 spacing between the words.

```css
.googlelogo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
}

.nav .gmail,
.nav .images {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='nav'>
    <a class='about' href='www.google.com/#'>About</a>
    <a class='store' href='www.google.com/#'>Store</a>
    <a class='images' href='www.google.com/#'>Images</a>
    <a class='gmail' href='www.google.com/#'>Gmail</a>

  </div>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img class='googlelogo' src='https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4019334/OGB-INSIDER-BLOGS-GoogleLogox2-Animated.0.gif' alt='Google logo' height='100'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `display: flex` with `justify-content: space-between` could achieve this. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/14uzmpwy/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the sections into `nav-left` and `nav-right`and use `flexbox` to equally space them.

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
.googlelogo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.nav { /* Added CSS for Flexbox */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
}

.nav .gmail,
.nav .images {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='nav'>
    <div class="nav-left"> <!-- Added HTML: Left Section Wrap -->
      <a class='about' href='www.google.com/#'>About</a>
      <a class='store' href='www.google.com/#'>Store</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right"> <!-- Added HTML: Right Section Wrap -->
      <a class='images' href='www.google.com/#'>Images</a>
      <a class='gmail' href='www.google.com/#'>Gmail</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img class='googlelogo' src='images/google.png' alt='Google logo' height='100'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This creates 4 evenly spaced words, how can I modify the flexbox in order to get 2 on one side, 2 on the other side?

Comment: Not really. Please check the example again. I have divided the section into two in the HTML.

Comment: Oh, my bad! Didn't notice that - definitely makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: right` for right aligning (if you add `float: right` to `.nav .gmail, .nav .images` it applies to both so instead surround the two in a div and apply to that.

```css
.googlelogo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
}
.nav .pull-right {
  float:right;
}
.nav::after{
clear: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='nav'>
    <a class='about' href='www.google.com/#'>About</a>
    <a class='store' href='www.google.com/#'>Store</a>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <a class='images' href='www.google.com/#'>Images</a>
      <a class='gmail' href='www.google.com/#'>Gmail</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img class='googlelogo' src='images/google.png' alt='Google logo' height='100'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should put a clearing element (or better yet, an `::after` pseudo-element) inside of `.nav`. A `float` without a `clear` is a major no-no.

Comment: The question states that this was already tried and yielded unsatisfactory results. Can you address that in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.googlelogo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
}

.nav .gmail,
.nav .images {}

.nav .gmail, .images {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='nav'>
    <a class='about' href='www.google.com/#'>About</a>
    <a class='store' href='www.google.com/#'>Store</a>
    <a class='images' href='www.google.com/#'>Images</a>
    <a class='gmail' href='www.google.com/#'>Gmail</a>

  </div>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img class='googlelogo' src='https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4019334/OGB-INSIDER-BLOGS-GoogleLogox2-Animated.0.gif' alt='Google logo' height='100'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Similar to what I said on another answer, but `float`s without `clear`s is a bad habit to get in to. Consider adding a clearing element or a pseudo-element like `::after` to accomplish that.

Comment: This code works, but the issue I'm having is the right "Gmail" and "Images" are shifted down further than the left side if I try to increase the space between the words.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex layout for your code.

Update your CSS with below code:

```
.nav{
  display:flex;  
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

and change html to:

```
<div class='nav'>
    <div>
      <a class='about' href='www.google.com/#'>About</a>
      <a class='store' href='www.google.com/#'>Store</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class='images' href='www.google.com/#'>Images</a>
      <a class='gmail' href='www.google.com/#'>Gmail</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This results in all of the `.nav a` items being on the right, which is not the desired result.

Comment: oh yeah, I thought user want all nav items to the right side.
for that, you have to change `justify-content: flex-end` to `justify-content: space-around`

Thanks for inform me @sean

Comment: That also will not yield the desired result. Please reread the question carefully.

Comment: @sean, I think now I am doing okay.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I think it will meet up your requirement. I have added some lines of code at bottom of the css file and separate them by a comment. I used flexbox technique to solve the problem. Hope it will be helpful to you.

```css
.googlelogo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
  margin-right: 2vw;
}

/* These are the code I've newly added */
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.nav .images {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='nav'>
    <a class='about' href='www.google.com/#'>About</a>
    <a class='store' href='www.google.com/#'>Store</a>
    <a class='images' href='www.google.com/#'>Images</a>
    <a class='gmail' href='www.google.com/#'>Gmail</a>

  </div>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img class='googlelogo' src='https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4019334/OGB-INSIDER-BLOGS-GoogleLogox2-Animated.0.gif' alt='Google logo' height='100'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```